# How do I query for a specific MongoDB collection field inside Rails Console?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, rails-console

I have a Rails 3 app using MongoDB, with Mongoid as the ORM. I'd like to query for a specific field within a collection.

To query for all records of a particular collection I use `User.all.to_a`, as an equivalent to `User.all` in ActiveRecord.

Now I'd like to query for all records within a collection, but only output a particular field. In this case I'd like to see all User names. How do I do this?

I'm sure I've stared right at this in the Mongoid documentation and am just missing something...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't locate it in the new documentation for mongoid, but here is a quick link to [only](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#only) pointing to old 2.x.x documentation.

Basically you need to do:

```
User.all.only(:name).to_a
```

Comment: Didn't work for me... both `User.all.only(:name).to_a` and `User.only(:name).to_a` dump out an array of all the User documents including all the related fields.

If do something like `User.all.distinct(:name)` it gives me an output of the appropriate :name field only. Not sure why your suggestion doesn't work. Seems like it should...

Comment: That's how it works in Mongoid, you'll won't get back just the field, values but each document with only that field populated. You could always map the array, but that could be inefficient, depending on your context. Something like: `User.only(:name).all.to_a.map{|u| u.name}`.

Comment: @J.Venator using `only`, only the specified fields are returned from db in form of a document and mongoid wraps them in a Model instance. `distinct` however only returns array of specified values. May be I misunderstood the question and you require `distinct`